# LINQ2SQL with MS SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2: BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I am having trouble using a .sdf database file with Ling2SQL. I am working with VS2010 on .NET 3.5. What I have done so far:

1. Created sdf file and added tables and data (located in project folder)
2. Copied SQLMetal.exe and SqlMetal.exe.config to the project folder and called it with:

   ```
   SQLMetal.exe database.sdf /dbml:DataOffline.dbml /namespace:CTcalc /pluralize
   ```
3. Added dbml file to the project (designer.cs is created)
4. Add new method to designer.cs

   ```
   public DataOfflineDataContext() : 
           base(global::CTcalc.Properties.Settings.Default.databaseOfflineConnectionString, mappingSource)
   {
       OnCreated();
   }
   ```
5. Add connectionString to settings file (type:connectionString)

   ```
   Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database.sdf
   ```
6. Using the connection:

   ```
   using (DataOfflineDataContext dc = new DataOfflineDataContext())
               lProtFunc = (from c in dc.ProtectionFunctions select c).ToList();
   ```

When debugging my project, I get an BadImageFormatException error with HRESULT: 0x8007000B

I have no idea how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: BadImageFormatException usually means a difference in x64 vs x86 assemblies.  What is the architecture of your machine? Are you hosting in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault was using the wrong .dll within my project.

I used

```
Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

instead of

```
Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Private\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

Now it is working!

Answer (score 0):

You must install both the x86 and x64 runtimes on your x64 system - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5783