# Linq-to-SQL (dbml) with Local database cache (C#+VS2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, synchronization

I'm developing a WPF application, which connects MS SQL2008 database remotely.
The app communicates with the database by Linq-to-SQL. pretty handy.

However, because of the slow database server, I'm trying to use local database caching.

"VS2010 > Add Item > Local database cache" wizard could be a solution, but it uses DataSet and SQL Compact(*.sdf).

**I found Linq-To-SQL cannot generate classes from the SQL COMPACT edition!**
(when I drag tables, error pops up and says 'unsupported data provider')

So, **is there any solution to use Linq-to-SQL with local database cache?**

or is there any database sync method played with Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-with-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226180/linq2sql-with-ms-sql-server-compact-3-5-sp2-badimageformatexception might help - SqlMetal is part of the solution

Comment: you'd better check why the database server is so slow. Perhaps you are having a Linq2sql n+1 queries problem? Have you profiled the sql?

Comment: @Pleun: It is connecting *remotely*, so it could be a number of things. Could be a problem with the database, could be network latency, or a host of other problems.

Comment: Well, it seems to me you are working on a solution before you know what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to go the sql compact way, Lightspeed is a linq-to-sql provider that supports a variety of data-sources. it includes mssql compact.

http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed

The free version is sufficient for most projects, with an 8 model/class limit.

Ive used it as a linq provider for MySql and Sql Compact before and it's been great.

You can see everything it supports and how it compares to other existing systems like it here:

http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed/comparing-lightspeed

Comment: I marked as answer that it is adequate to apply to my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the Local Database Cache Wizard only supports SQL Ce on the client side. if you have SQL Express/SQL Server on the client side, you can use Sync Framework still.

see following samples/tutorials using Sync Framework:

[Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928676.aspx)

[Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express 2-Tier](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-a9752fac)

nevermind if it mentions SQLExpress, the SQLSyncProvider referenced in the code should work against SQL Express,SQL Server, and SQL Azure